# Does duplicating lists lead to memory leaks?

Tags: c#, linq, list, memory-leaks

Does this create memory leaks if used in cycles?

```
mylist = mylist.Distinct().ToList();
```

If so, whats a good approach for lists if you only need to update it(particularly with LINQ), not to create a new one?

Comment: There is no "if so".

Comment: You mean there are no memory leaks? The old list is always taken care of after using LINQ?

Comment: I think you're confusing 'using extra memory' with 'memory leaks'. This will not cause a memory leak, the original list will be automatically cleaned up by the GC.

Comment: Does a water tap leak if you open it?

Comment: Hm, this code is no special case to memory leaks in .NET. Any object that is still being referenced will stay alive. Any object that you drop will be deleted eventually. Why do you think this particular piece of code is special?

Answer (score 1):

The cited line of code:

```
mylist = mylist.Distinct().ToList();
```

will create a new object of type `List<T>`, where `T` is `typeof(mylist)`.

The list will contain references to a subset (possibly all, or none) of the original objects in `mylist`, as returned by the `Distinct()` LINQ operator.

Therefore, the situation you have after that line of code is that you have the original list, all of the original objects that were in the original list, plus a new list that references some subset of the original objects.

So yes, you've used a bit more memory (but not much, relatively speaking).

That in itself is not a *memory leak*. That would depend what you now do with your new list. If you simply set it to null, or it goes out of scope, then it will normally be garbage collected (eventually) and you'll get all the memory back; no leak. However, if you do something that causes another object to hold a reference to your list, then you could potentially have a memory leak.

Some ways that you could unknowingly be holding a reference to your new list include:

- A lambda expression has 'closed over' the list variable and the lambda has been passed to another object. The list will then have the lifetime of the other object, even if it is out of lexical scope.
- You've subscribed to an event on another object; the other object now holds a reference (via a delegate) to your object and it will be kept alive while the event subscription persists.
- I'm sure there are others...